# way to prove monotonicity of function

Tags: calculus

I want to prove that the function $f(x)=x\sin x+\cos x-x^2$ is down monotonic on $(0,\infty)$.
I know exactly that I need to prove that to every $x_1<x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1)>f(x_2)$.

It's easy to prove it if the function was for example $-x^2$. but I don't know how to do it with the $x\sin x$ and $\cos x$, especially because they are periodic at the domain of $f(x)$.

Without calculating a derivative.

Comment: The function is differentiable, so looking at the derivative is a natural idea.

Comment: Yes,I see that. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Derive the function and you will find:
$$
x \cos x + \sin x - \sin x -2x
$$
which equals
$$
x(\cos x - 2)
$$
and since the cosine of a real numer is always smaller than $1$ this expression is negative for all positive $x$. This means that the function is by definition decreasing.

Comment: Not “by definition”, but by Lagrange's theorem

Comment: The notion of a decreasing function has to be defined before you can make statements about a function being decreasing. Lagrange's theorem can only be stated once you have defined what it means for a function to be decreasing/increasing

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Also called "mean value theorem"